# Visual Studio custom include path makes symbol error when linking

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I have custom include directory that added to project proproperties.

- former question: [C++ linker strange behavior: static member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465140/c-linker-strange-behavior-static-member-variable)

When I put my .h and .cpp file into project and project directory, there's no problem at all.
But when I try to use same file in custom include path, `LNK2005` linker error occurs--especially a class that has `static` member.

Here's my code:

```
/* graphics_app.h */
#ifndef DK_GRAPHICS_APP_H
#define DK_GRAPHICS_APP_H
...    
class GraphicsApp {
private:
    static GraphicsApp* self;

public:
    ...

#endif /* DK_GRAPHICS_APP_H */
```

---

```
/* graphics_app.cpp */
#include "graphics_app.h"
...
GraphicsApp* GraphicsApp::self = nullptr;
```

---

When I try to use in project like this:

```
#include <dk\graphics_app.h>
```

I get these linker error(note that I use MSVC)

```
LNK2005 "private: static class GraphicsApp * GraphicsApp::self" (?self@GraphicsApp@@0PEAV1@EA) already defined in main.obj.
LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found.
```

But, if I add `graphics_app.h` and `graphics_app.cpp` file to project and project directory like this:

```
#include "graphics_app.h"
```

makes no error.

So I made much simpler version of these, but same problems are repeated.
A file contains only empty `main` and `#include <graphics_app.h>` line makes same error. Because of that `static`.

What am I missing?

Comment: The problem is most likely not with the header file, but the source file. Do you build with it multiple times?

Comment: Yes, I tried with class that has only static member, and included to just-empty-main() code. But when I use it, same error occurs--because  of `static` member symbol already defined.

Comment: and this error didn't occured until yesterday. Even I put static member definition on .h file

Comment: Your main is somehow instantiating `self`.  (`GraphicsApp* GraphicsApp::self;`)  Either you are doing that, or you are including a header (or even cpp?) that does.

Comment: The paranoid approach is you could do a Project->Clean, then 'Find in Files' (probably ctrl-shift-f), `Look in` and select the root of your project *directory* (so that it includes your include directories), look at ALL file types (`*.*`), and find `GraphicsApp::self`.  You should only see it in ONE file:  graphics_app.cpp.  And if you have more than one copy of that file, that's begging for trouble.

Comment: Of course, once you start actually *using* that variable, you'll see it elsewhere, but it sounds like you aren't at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It was misunderstood of *include path*.

*Include path* only locate **.h** files. So unlike using standard headers or 3-rd party headers, the header what I made knows **decleration** of functions etc.

But *include path* cannot locate **.cpp** files, because it's **include** path. So what I have to do is to make a library or single-header.

Instead of making libraries, I chose this method: add **definition part**(.cpp) file to project.

I got concept. Thanks for replies!